# In XCode when I start a line with four or more forward slashes, the font changes to a small font. How do I turn this off?

Tags: xcode, formatting, comments

XCode switches to a slightly smaller variable width font on lines starting with 4 slashes.  If I put a space within the four slashes then it doesn't happen. I've tried turning off various options in the editor preferences but I can't figure out what this is related to. I'm using XCode 12.5.1. Here is what it looks like:

[image: XCode font problem example]

Comment: This lets you add quick help documentation/markdown - add 3 slashes `///`. Why do you want to turn it off?

Comment: Btw you can add markdown inside the comments - for example `/// **This is bold text!!**`

Comment: It messes up my comment formatting.

Comment: Try using `/* comment */` instead. Or just use `//`...

Answer (score 1):

Under Preferences->Themes you can change the font for "documentation markup" to change this font.  Apparently XCode does not include any way to turn this new documentation feature off.